# I am unable to edit the products details as the modal box doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add product details and then edit them. But the edit option doesn't come. It shows blank screen

```js
var manageProductTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
 // top nav bar 
 $('#navProduct').addClass('active');
 // manage product data table
 manageProductTable = $('#manageProductTable').DataTable({
  'ajax': 'phpaction/fetchinventory.php',
  'order': []
 });

 // add product modal btn clicked
 $("#addProductModalBtn").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
  // // product form reset
  $("#submitProductForm")[0].reset();  

  // remove text-error 
  $(".text-danger").remove();
  // remove from-group error
  $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

  
  $("#submitProductForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {

   // form validation
   
   var productName = $("#productName").val();
   var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
   var rate = $("#rate").val();
   
 
   
   if(productName == "") {
    $("#productName").after('<p class="text-danger">Product Name field is required</p>');
    $('#productName').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
   } else {
    // remov error text field
    $("#productName").find('.text-danger').remove();
    // success out for form 
    $("#productName").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');    
   } // /else

   if(quantity == "") {
    $("#quantity").after('<p class="text-danger">Quantity field is required</p>');
    $('#quantity').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
   } else {
    // remov error text field
    $("#quantity").find('.text-danger').remove();
    // success out for form 
    $("#quantity").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');    
   } // /else

   if(rate == "") {
    $("#rate").after('<p class="text-danger">Rate field is required</p>');
    $('#rate').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
   } else {
    // remov error text field
    $("#rate").find('.text-danger').remove();
    // success out for form 
    $("#rate").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');    
   } // /else

   

   if(productName && quantity && rate) {
    // submit loading button
    $("#createProductBtn").button('loading');

    var form = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
     url : form.attr('action'),
     type: form.attr('method'),
     data: formData,
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     success:function(response) {

      if(response.success == true) {
       // submit loading button
       $("#createProductBtn").button('reset');
       
       $("#submitProductForm")[0].reset();

       $("html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body").animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 100);
                 
       // shows a successful message after operation
       $('#add-product-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
              '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
            '</div>');

       // remove the mesages
            $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
        $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
         $(this).remove();
        });
       }); // /.alert

            // reload the manage student table
       manageProductTable.ajax.reload(null, true);

       // remove text-error 
       $(".text-danger").remove();
       // remove from-group error
       $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

      } // /if response.success
      
     } // /success function
    }); // /ajax function
   }  // /if validation is ok      

   return false;
  }); // /submit product form

 }); // /add product modal btn clicked
 

 // remove product  

}); // document.ready fucntion


function editProduct(productId = null) {

 if(productId) {
  $("#productId").remove();  
  // remove text-error 
  $(".text-danger").remove();
  // remove from-group error
  $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
  // modal spinner
  $('.div-loading').removeClass('div-hide');
  // modal div
  $('.div-result').addClass('div-hide');

  $.ajax({
   url: 'phpaction/fetchselectedinventory.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {productId: productId},
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(response) {  
   // alert(response.product_image);
    // modal spinner
    $('.div-loading').addClass('div-hide');
    // modal div
    $('.div-result').removeClass('div-hide');     

    // $("#editProductImage").fileinput({
    //     overwriteInitial: true,
    //    maxFileSize: 2500,
    //    showClose: false,
    //    showCaption: false,
    //    browseLabel: '',
    //    removeLabel: '',
    //    browseIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>',
    //    removeIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
    //    removeTitle: 'Cancel or reset changes',
    //    elErrorContainer: '#kv-avatar-errors-1',
    //    msgErrorClass: 'alert alert-block alert-danger',
    //    defaultPreviewContent: '<img src="stock/'+response.product_image+'" alt="Profile Image" style="width:100%;">',
    //    layoutTemplates: {main2: '{preview} {remove} {browse}'},            
    //   allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "gif", "JPG", "PNG", "GIF"]
    // });  

    // product id 
    $(".editProductFooter").append('<input type="hidden" name="productId" id="productId" value="'+response.product_id+'" />');    
    //$(".editProductPhotoFooter").append('<input type="hidden" name="productId" id="productId" value="'+response.product_id+'" />');    
    
    // product name
    $("#editProductName").val(response.productname);
    // rate
    $("#editRate").val(response.rate);
    // quantity
    $("#editQuantity").val(response.qty);

    // update the product data function
    $("#editProductForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {

     // form validation
     var productName = $("#editProductName").val();
     var quantity = $("#editQuantity").val();
     var rate = $("#editRate").val();

     if(productName == "") {
      $("#editProductName").after('<p class="text-danger">Product Name field is required</p>');
      $('#editProductName').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
     } else {
      // remov error text field
      $("#editProductName").find('.text-danger').remove();
      // success out for form 
      $("#editProductName").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');    
     } // /else

     if(quantity == "") {
      $("#editQuantity").after('<p class="text-danger">Quantity field is required</p>');
      $('#editQuantity').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
     } else {
      // remov error text field
      $("#editQuantity").find('.text-danger').remove();
      // success out for form 
      $("#editQuantity").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');    
     } // /else

     if(rate == "") {
      $("#editRate").after('<p class="text-danger">Rate field is required</p>');
      $('#editRate').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
     } else {
      // remov error text field
      $("#editRate").find('.text-danger').remove();
      // success out for form 
      $("#editRate").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');    
     } // /else

     
     if(productName && quantity && rate) {
      // submit loading button
      $("#editProductBtn").button('loading');

      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData(this);

      $.ajax({
       url : form.attr('action'),
       type: form.attr('method'),
       data: formData,
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.success == true) {
         // submit loading button
         $("#editProductBtn").button('reset');                  

         $("html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body").animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 100);
                   
         // shows a successful message after operation
         $('#edit-product-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
                '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
              '</div>');

         // remove the mesages
              $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
          $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
           $(this).remove();
          });
         }); // /.alert

              // reload the manage student table
         manageProductTable.ajax.reload(null, true);

         // remove text-error 
         $(".text-danger").remove();
         // remove from-group error
         $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

        } // /if response.success
        
       } // /success function
      }); // /ajax function
     }  // /if validation is ok      

     return false;
    }); // update the product data function

              // reload the manage student table
         /*manageProductTable.ajax.reload(null, true);

         $(".fileinput-remove-button").click();                

         // remove text-error 
         $(".text-danger").remove();
         // remove from-group error
         $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

        } // /if response.success
        
       } // /success function
      }); // /ajax function
     }*/  // /if validation is ok 
     {
      // submit loading button
      //$("#editProductImageBtn").button('loading');

      var form = $(this);
      var formData = new FormData(this);

      $.ajax({
       url : form.attr('action'),
       type: form.attr('method'),
       data: formData,
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success:function(response) {
        
        if(response.success == true) {
         // submit loading button
         //$("#editProductImageBtn").button('reset');                  

         $("html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body").animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 100);
                   
         // shows a successful message after operation
         /*$('#edit-productPhoto-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
                '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
              '</div>');*/

         // remove the mesages
              $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
          $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
           $(this).remove();
          });
         }); // /.alert

              // reload the manage student table
         manageProductTable.ajax.reload(null, true);

         //$(".fileinput-remove-button").click();

         /*$.ajax({
          url: 'php_action/fetchProductImageUrl.php?i='+productId,
          type: 'post',
          success:function(response) {
          $("#getProductImage").attr('src', response);  
          }
         });*/                  

         // remove text-error 
         $(".text-danger").remove();
         // remove from-group error
         $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

        } // /if response.success
        
       } // /success function
      }); // /ajax function
     }     

     return false;
    //}); // /update the product image

   } // /success function
  }); // /ajax to fetch product image

    
 } else {
  alert('error please refresh the page');
 }
} // /edit product function

/*
// remove product 
function removeProduct(productId = null) {
 if(productId) {
  // remove product button clicked
  $("#removeProductBtn").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
   // loading remove button
   $("#removeProductBtn").button('loading');
   $.ajax({
    url: 'phpaction/removeProduct.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {productId: productId},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response) {
     // loading remove button
     $("#removeProductBtn").button('reset');
     if(response.success == true) {
      // remove product modal
      $("#removeProductModal").modal('hide');

      // update the product table
      manageProductTable.ajax.reload(null, false);

      // remove success messages
      $(".remove-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
              '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
            '</div>');

      // remove the mesages
           $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
       $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
        $(this).remove();
       });
      }); // /.alert
     } else {

      // remove success messages
      $(".removeProductMessages").html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
              '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> '+ response.messages +
            '</div>');

      // remove the mesages
           $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
       $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
        $(this).remove();
       });
      }); // /.alert

     } // /error
    } // /success function
   }); // /ajax fucntion to remove the product
   return false;
  }); // /remove product btn clicked
 } // /if productid
} // /remove product function
*/

function clearForm(oForm) {
 // var frm_elements = oForm.elements;         
 // console.log(frm_elements);
 //  for(i=0;i<frm_elements.length;i++) {
 //   field_type = frm_elements[i].type.toLowerCase();         
 //   switch (field_type) {
 //      case "text":
 //      case "password":
 //      case "textarea":
 //      case "hidden":
 //      case "select-one":     
 //        frm_elements[i].value = "";
 //        break;
 //      case "radio":
 //      case "checkbox":     
 //        if (frm_elements[i].checked)
 //        {
 //            frm_elements[i].checked = false;
 //        }
 //        break;
 //      case "file": 
 //       if(frm_elements[i].options) {
 //        frm_elements[i].options= false;
 //       }
 //      default:
 //          break;
 //     } // /switch
 //  } // for
}
```

```html
<?php require_once 'phpaction/db_connect.php' ?>
<?php require_once 'phpaction/checksystemlogin.php' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Inventory</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!-- bootstrap theme-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <!-- font awesome -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- jquery -->
 <script src="assests/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- jquery ui -->  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
 <script src="assests/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <!-- bootstrap js -->
 <script src="assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">


   <ol class="breadcrumb">
     <li><a href="dashboard.php">Home</a></li>    
     <li class="active">Product</li>
   </ol>

   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="page-heading"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Manage Product</div>
    </div> <!-- /panel-heading -->
    <div class="panel-body">

     <div class="remove-messages"></div>

     <div class="div-action pull pull-right" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
      <button class="btn btn-default button1" data-toggle="modal" id="addProductModalBtn" data-target="#addProductModal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> Add Product </button>
     </div> <!-- /div-action -->    
     
     <table class="table" id="manageProductTable">
      <thead>
       <tr>       
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Rate</th>      
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th style="width:15%;">Options</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
     </table>
     <!-- /table -->
    </div> <!-- /panel-body -->
   </div> <!-- /panel -->  
  </div> <!-- /col-md-12 -->
 </div> <!-- /row -->


 <!-- add product -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="addProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">

      <form class="form-horizontal" id="submitProductForm" action="phpaction/addinventory.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Product</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:450px; overflow:auto;">

         <div id="add-product-messages"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="productName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Name: </label>
           <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" placeholder="Product Name" name="productName" autocomplete="off">
         </div>
          </div> <!-- /form-group-->     

          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="quantity" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantity: </label>
           <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity" autocomplete="off">
         </div>
          </div> <!-- /form-group-->           

          <div class="form-group">
           <label for="rate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Rate: </label>
           <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rate" placeholder="Rate" name="rate" autocomplete="off">
         </div>
          </div> <!-- /form-group-->               

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i> Close</button>
          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="createProductBtn" data-loading-text="Loading..." autocomplete="off"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Save Changes</button>
        </div> <!-- /modal-footer -->       
       </form> <!-- /.form -->      
     </div> <!-- /modal-content -->    
   </div> <!-- /modal-dailog -->
 </div> 
 <!-- /add categories -->


 <!-- edit categories brand -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="editProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
           
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Product</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:450px; overflow:auto;">

         <div class="div-loading">
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
       <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
         </div>

         <div class="div-result">

       <!-- Nav tabs -->
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        
         <li role="presentation"><a href="#productInfo" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Product Info</a></li>    
       </ul>

       <!-- Tab panes -->
       <div class="tab-content">
         <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="productInfo">
          <form class="form-horizontal" id="editProductForm" action="phpaction/editinventory.php" method="POST">        
          <br />

          <div id="edit-product-messages"></div>

          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="editProductName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Name: </label>
             <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
           <div class="col-sm-8">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editProductName" placeholder="Product Name" name="editProductName" autocomplete="off">
           </div>
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->     

            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="editQuantity" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantity: </label>
             <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
           <div class="col-sm-8">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editQuantity" placeholder="Quantity" name="editQuantity" autocomplete="off">
           </div>
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->           

            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="editRate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Rate: </label>
             <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
           <div class="col-sm-8">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editRate" placeholder="Rate" name="editRate" autocomplete="off">
           </div>
            </div> <!-- /form-group-->               

                   

            <div class="modal-footer editProductFooter">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i> Close</button>
             
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="editProductBtn" data-loading-text="Loading..."> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Save Changes</button>
           </div> <!-- /modal-footer -->         
            </form> <!-- /.form -->          
         </div>    
         <!-- /product info -->
       </div>

     </div>
         
        </div> <!-- /modal-body -->
               
       
     </div>
     <!-- /modal-content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /modal-dailog -->
 </div>
 <!-- /categories brand -->
 <!-- categories brand -->
<!-- <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="removeProductModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Remove Product</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="removeProductMessages"></div>

         <p>Do you really want to remove ?</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer removeProductFooter">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i> Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="removeProductBtn" data-loading-text="Loading..."> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Save changes</button>
       </div>
     </div>
-->

 <script src="custom/js/product.js"></script>
 <!-- file input -->
 <script src="assests/plugins/fileinput/js/plugins/canvas-to-blob.min.js'); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="assests/plugins/fileinput/js/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="assests/plugins/fileinput/js/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assests/plugins/fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js"></script> 


 <!-- DataTables -->
 <script src="assests/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make online inventory management system.
when I click the edit option, the edit product modal does not show up. Instead a blank screen comes and then I can't access that. 
All the other php files are running but the modal does not show up.